# What is the major difference between CGAffineTransformMake and CGAffineTransformMakeRotation?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cgaffinetransform

What is the difference between :

```
self.viewBG.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
```

and

```
self.viewBG.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
```

I am using table view in my chat application and i transform table with above method so please help me out on this.

Which one is better and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGAffineTransformMake` allows you to set the individual matrix values of the transform directly, whereas `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` takes that work away from you and allows you to ask for a transform that rotates something by the amount you want, without you having to understand how the matrix works. The end result is the same.

The second option is much better - it is obvious what the transform is doing and by how much. Any readers that don't understand how the matrix maths of  transforms work or what those individual unnamed parameters mean (which is going to be virtually all readers, myself included) are not going to know what the first line is doing.

Readability always wins.

Comment: Agreed. Also the rotation by M_PI is equal to CGAffineTransformMake(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0), there was a little mistake in the question. Which kind of proves the point of using the simplest, most readable function.

Answer (score 0):

The `CGAffineTransformMake` lets you set the transform yourself, while the others basically are convenience methods to do it for you.

For example, `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` evaluates to this:

`t' = [ cos(angle) sin(angle) -sin(angle) cos(angle) 0 0 ]`

Note that the result is not the same. Using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` will result in (*rounded values*) `[-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 ]`. There is also an accuracy aspect. The trigonometric functions do not always evaluate to the exact value you expect. In this case, `sin(-M_PI)` actual becomes `-0.00000000000000012246467991473532` instead of zero because of inaccuracy of PI, I presume.

Personally, I always use the convenience methods, as the code is much easier to understand. The inaccuracy is usually something you wont notice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

CGAffineTransformMake : Returns an affine transformation matrix constructed from values you provide.

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation : Returns an affine transformation matrix constructed from a rotation value you provide.

Source URL : http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/function_group_1.html